# Computer keeps restarting for no reason

Tags: windows-10, reboot, random

My computer keeps restarting randomly for no reason. It can happen after 5 hours of use or it can happen after only 10 minutes of startup. I’m not quite sure what it could be but I don’t think it’s cpu overheating.

My Specs are as follow:

ASU’s ROG Strix RTX 2060 Super,
Ryzen 5 3600x,
Aorus B450 Elite,
16 GB 3600Mhz Corsair Vengeance,
Gigabyte P650B Plus Bronze 650W PSU

Comment: Usually a fault in your operating system or the power supply can not handle your configuration, I believe the latter.

Comment: I switched out my power supply with my old one and the problem still occurs. If it were my operating system what would I have to do to fix it?

Comment: Here is an article talking about [How do I fix computer keeps restarting?](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/how-do-i-fix-computer-keeps-restarting/), you could have a look.